# What JavaScript Frameworks are available to consume ASP.NET Web API Services

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api, javascript, javascript-framework

I heard of [Breeze.js](http://www.breezejs.com/)

Is there any other JavaScript framework (api) available to consume web services?

Basically I want to make a client side GET request to a ASP.NET Web API and transform the response to a JavaScript object.
I want to keep the web app as simple as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a framework to consume web services from Web API, JavaScript has that ability natively.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

However, just about every JS framework has some type of helper to make these calls easy. Here are just a few:

- jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- Dojo: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request.html
- Prototype: http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/ajax/Ajax/Request/

Answer (score 1):

You already have that built-in with asp.net web api.

by default it will return `JSON` (and you can tell it to return xml if you want by setting the accept header when requesting).

Try something out.